# print only user's variables in interactive mode

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am in the interactive mode of the python 3 interpreter.

I have created some variables of different data types. After some time I want to see a list of all variables that I have created. I tried using `dir()`; but this also shows the special python builtin variables:
`['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']`

How can I print only my variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to exclude them is something like this:

```
[val for val in dir() if val.strip('__') == val]
```

Just don't define any variables that start or end with `__`.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot! I will try to include this line of code in a separate .py file and then will try to execute it in the interactive mode.

Comment: Sure. Putting it in its own function will make it easier to reuse as well. If I've solved your problem, please feel free to accept my answer.